# Open uncommited files in Android studio

Tags: android-studio, atlassian-sourcetree

I have been working on several java and xml files in android studio.
Now when done, i want to open the all modified files all at once to review them before a commit.
Something similar to `git status` and then `git show` for each and every one of them.

I can do it manually of course but i was wondering is there a better way to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for the [Local Changes](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/log-tab.html#changedFiles) part of the **Version Control** tab (Alt+9). There you can check the changes, though you need to open them one-by-one.

If you open (Ctrl+K) the Commit dialog, you can also check the diffs easily within the window, I find that very useful:
[image: Open the Diff panel]

Comment: thanks, it is a good answer and i already use that. 
How ever  i was looking for a way or a tool for an easy and more organized review

Comment: @soosita I have updated the answer with a different option, maybe that fits your workflow better.